# How to add the optional menu css class to body_class?

Tags: wordpress

I’m trying to figure out how to add the menu class (optional field in admin) to the `body_class`, as I want to use the menu item's color on other elements of the page:

```
/** Add nav menu css class to body class */
function add_nav_menu_css( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = ‘optional-menu-class’;
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( ‘body_class’, ‘add_nav_menu_css’ );
```

What should replace 'optional-menu-class'?

Comment: can you please rephrase that, what are you trying to add to the `body_class` ?

Comment: I'm trying to add the css class that you can add to each menu item in wp-admin (screen options, advanced menu properties, css classes)

Comment: i have added an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i could find is to use `wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID)`

i tested it below with my menu `id` of `7`

```
$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 7 );
foreach ($items as $i) {
    echo $i->classes[0];
}
```

outputs `sample-page-class` which I inputed on the appearance menu page.

All of the menu classes are stored in the function `wp_get_nav_menu_items` as classes so then you can just loop them out with a `foreach` like i did above.

and then transfer that data to the `body_class`.

#### Further Explained:

So your `body_class` filter in the functions.php should like

```
add_filter('body_class','add_nav_menu_css');
function add_nav_menu_css($classes) {

        $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 7 ); // change to id of your menu

        foreach ($items as $i) {
                $menuClasses .= $i->classes[0].' ';
        }

        $classes[] = $menuClasses;


        return $classes;
}
```

#### Edited for Current Classes only

input to the functions.php page

```
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
function my_class_names($classes) 
{
        $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 7 ); //change to suit your menu id
          foreach ($items as $item):
                $menuClasses = $item->classes;
                $objectId = $item->object_id.' ';

                if ( is_page($item->object_id) ):
                    $current[] = $menuClasses;
                endif;



          endforeach;

        $classes[] =  $current[0][0];


        return $classes;
}
```

the documentation is [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items)

Comment: It works! except that it prints all the classes, and not the selected menu item

Comment: it should have printed all of the classes that you add to each of items in the appearance->menu correct?

Comment: Yes, it printed all of them. However, I need it to only print the one of the selected item.

Comment: why not use the page title as a body class, that way each page has a unique class that you can use..

Comment: I don't want to get into that, because the page titles might change. Also, it may become a custom post type, so I just wanted to use the menu's class option for this.

Comment: Is there maybe a way of retrieving the current item and it's class?

Comment: do you mean like this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/how-to-get-current-menu-item-title-as-variable ?

Comment: Yes, something like that, so if we know the current menu item, can we then retrieve it's class

Comment: thanks so much for your help! It works! I now need to change it so that it works for posts as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a custom class to the body tag simply use the body class,

```
<body <?php body_class('class-name'); ?>>
```

where 'class-name' is your custom class, 
if you want this to change based on or page/post, simply add this to your header.php

```
<?php
if(is_page('your-page-name')){// or post
  $body_class = 'your-custom-page-class';
}
?>
<body <?php body_class($class_name); ?>>
```

you could also change the class based on category name.

```
<?php
if( !is_front_page() && is_category() || is_single() ){
   // category single name
   $cat_name = single_cat_title('',false);
   // category id from category name
   $cat_id = get_category_id($cat_name);
   $body_class = $cat_name;
}
?>
<body <?php body_class($body_class); ?>>
```

hopefully that works out for u.

M

ps: just seen your update
have a look here, 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20110/add-custom-class-to-wp-nav-menu-using-filter-hook-nav-menu-css-class

Comment: i think he's trying to get a specific class from the menu, that he added and knows how to add a class to the `body_class`

Comment: yea just seen that after I posted.. :|

Comment: Thanks Marty, but David is right, I need to get the name of the css class that I entered for the menu item

Comment: I saw that post before, but it's not exactly the problem. I specified a css class for each of my menu items so that they each have a different colour (.cyan, .magenta, .green, etc.). What I want to do is to put that class name into the body_class so that I can use it on the page titles, etc, it doesn't matter if it's a page or a custom post type.

Comment: ok so how are your menus created? categories? pages? or custom links?the reason i ask is that if its based on category, you can use the above to assign a colour to any category being used, then assign that category to the body tag?

Comment: It's a mix. I don't want to get into using category names in the css as these can change.

Comment: does my answer below not help?